# How to load JPG/PNG Textures in an SDL/OpenGL App under OSX

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, png, jpeg

i am writing an SDL / OpenGL application that runs under OSX. I have to use existing code which uses the DevIL library for loading JPG and PNG textures. Unfortunately, this works very bad under OS X, so i decided not to use DevIL at all, and rewrite the respective parts of the application using another library. I want to keep it flexible (DevIL can handle a lot of image formats) and easy to use. Is there a good replacement for DevIL that you can recommend? The application is entirely written in C++.

Comment: Why do you think that using JPEG, PNG, <put your favorite image format here> is good idea to store textures?

Comment: As n0rd alludes to, you only need support for standard image formats at compile-time.  The build process should convert all your graphic resources to a common format.  This also reduces the work your app needs to do at startup, so it will load faster.

Comment: good point! i'll probably stick with just PNG images.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the [SDL_image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) library. It offers functions like `IMG_LoadPNG` that load your picture "as an" SDL_Surface.
Since you already work with SDL this should fit quite well in your program.

Sample taken from the [SDL_image documentation](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_frame.html):

```
// Load sample.png into image
SDL_Surface* image = IMG_Load("sample.png");
if (image == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "IMG_Load: " << IMG_GetError() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**SDL 2 SDL_image minimal runnable example**

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

int main(void) {
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(
        500, 500,
        0, &window, &renderer
    );
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    texture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "flower.png");
    while (1) {
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) && event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            break;
    }
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/82d70fcf50397e65098453320ba384d660355b61/sdl/png.c).

Compile and run:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev
gcc -std=c99 -o main -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.c -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
./main
```

Outcome:

[image]

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, GCC 6.4.0, SDL 2.0.4, SDL Image 2.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [freeimage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/). It supports all major formats and is easily built with macports. Nice to work with as well. Auto-detects image format etc.

```
FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT format = FreeImage_GetFileType(filename.c_str(), 0);
FIBITMAP *bitmap = FreeImage_Load(format, filename.c_str());
if (!bitmap)
{
    LOG_ERROR("Unable to load texture: " + filename);
    return false;
}
mlWidth = FreeImage_GetWidth(bitmap);
mlHeight = FreeImage_GetHeight(bitmap);
glGenTextures(1, &mpTextures[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mpTextures[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,     GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,     GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, mlWidth, mlHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
       (GLvoid*)FreeImage_GetBits(bitmap));
FreeImage_Unload(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Mac OS anyway, why not just use [CGImageSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html) to do the loading? OS X natively supports loading many file formats including PNG and JPEG.

Comment: From a quick look that doesn't look at all like C++. That would be one reason.