# Displaying an .bmp image in C++/SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have been having trouble displaying an image in an SDL window and I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong. The code compiles just fine and the image has been placed in the debug folder with my .exe so I am not sure why it is not displaying. Is there something minor I may have missed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#undef main

using namespace std;

const int screenWidth = 640;
const int screenHeight = 480;

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {

SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, screenWidth, screenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_Surface* image = SDL_LoadBMP("image.bmp");
SDL_Renderer* render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
SDL_Texture* texture1 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(render, image);

SDL_RenderCopy(render, texture1, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderPresent(render);

SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

SDL_Delay(5000);

SDL_DestroyTexture(texture1);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(render);
SDL_FreeSurface(image);
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `image`? If NULL, what `SDL_GetError()` says? Relative paths are relative to current working directory, not '.exe folder', which may be quite different things. Remove `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` as you already use renderer and cannot combine surface with it. Last but not least, make rendering loop and redraw at least on window events (or, simplier, redraw unconditionally); drawing once & sleeping is not a way to display things.

Comment: On Linux your code works just fine as it is, as @keltar wrote [SDL_GetError](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError) should help. Maybe something in the image file format?

Comment: Minimal runnable working PNG example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153055/how-to-load-jpg-png-textures-in-an-sdl-opengl-app-under-osx/41686559#41686559 Will likely be easy to adapt to bmp as docs say it is supported: https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you step through the code in a debugger, and inspect the
return-values in each step, do you get something unexpected?
Such as a nullpointer. That is probably going to help you
narrow it down.

> image has been placed in the debug folder with my .exe

If you run from the IDE, the current working folder is going
to be the project folder.

Comment: Thank you! The issue was it was supposed to be in the folder with the project instead.